# Fixed wireless then bluetooth stopped working

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, intel-wireless, xps

I've tried doing a recovery, deleted unnecessary packages. I'm a bit baffled because after updating the kernel to include the new Intel 7260 driver (to get the wifi working) Bluetooth worked a few times and then stopped after restarting to update system packages.

Now the options to add a Bluetooth device have disappeared and only shows "Bluetooth: Off" and "Turn On Bluetooth" and "Bluetooth Settings"

It seems that maybe I changed something when updated and restarted the system, but I'm not sure what? I've run `sudo apt-get update` followed by a `sudo apt-get upgrade`, seems that no packages are needed for download.

I've included some diagnostics below. If anyone could refer me to another similar solution online (I've been looking for a while, this seems to be very similar to my situation and hasn't received a response: [Bluetooth adapter turned from working fine to unrecognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202426/bluetooth-adapter-turned-from-working-fine-to-unrecognized/342995#342995))

Screenshows of what I see:

[image: image1]

and

[image: image2]

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:5716 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:09fa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

**sudo rfkill list**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**sudo lshw**

```
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:59 memory:f7d10000-f7d13fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:df200000-df3fffff ioport:df400000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 memory:f7c00000-f7cfffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 7260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                logical name: wlan1
                version: 6b
                serial: 5c:51:4f:1c:8a:f4
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.11.0-intelwireless-wl firmware=22.0.7.0 ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                resources: irq:58 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7d1b000-f7d1b3ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz42: USB 00.0: 11500 Bluetooth Device
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:57 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7d1a000-f7d1a7ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7d19000-f7d190ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-scsi
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: LITEONIT LMT-256
             physical id: 0.0.0mark@mark-XPS-12-9Q33:~$ sudo hciconfig hci0 reset                 bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: DM81
             serial: TW0XXM30550853850829
             size: 238GiB (256GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=b27ee8c2-4f94-4aee-bb34-dadf65e11b0f
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: 0c97-4e89
                size: 495MiB
                capacity: 499MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI system partition state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: FAT32
                serial: e0f9-9180
                size: 15MiB
                capacity: 39MiB
                capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=Basic data partition
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows reserved partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                serial: f21bffb4-6790-48c7-a3cd-04aa701961e6
                capacity: 127MiB
                capabilities: nofs
                configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                version: 3.1
                serial: fefd-fa12
                size: 460MiB
                capacity: 489MiB
                capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-08-29 00:41:13 filesystem=ntfs label=WINRETOOLS name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:4
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 5
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
                logical name: /dev/sda5
                version: 3.1
                serial: ce32f619-10cd-3540-93d7-40ee173568ea
                size: 158GiB
                capacity: 158GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-08-29 00:41:30 filesystem=ntfs label=OS name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:5
                description: EFI partition
                physical id: 6
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,6
                logical name: /dev/sda6
                serial: 5565cdb4-f266-4c46-b718-f92b0c33178c
                capacity: 8197MiB
                configuration: name=Basic data partition
           *-volume:6
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 7
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,7
                logical name: /dev/sda7
                version: 3.1
                serial: 74e8-1e5f
                size: 11GiB
                capacity: 11GiB
                capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-08-29 01:59:21 filesystem=ntfs label=PBR Image modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Microsoft recovery partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:7
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 8
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,8
                logical name: /dev/sda8
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: ed66b002-bb2f-4b8e-a8a9-82df9cc4a2e5
                size: 59GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2013-09-05 19:25:30 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2013-09-07 15:56:55 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2013-09-08 13:10:26 state=mounted
  *-battery
       description: Lithium Ion Battery
       product: DELL 7YM0737
       vendor: SDI
       physical id: 1
       version: Not Specified
       serial: Not Specified
       slot: System Battery
       capacity: 51060mWh
       configuration: voltage=7.4V
```

**hwinfo**

```
42: USB 00.0: 11500 Bluetooth Device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: 7bWa.cdUiY6836R9
  Parent ID: pBe4.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 2-3:1.0
  Hardware Class: bluetooth
  Model: "Bluetooth Device"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x8087 
  Device: usb 0x07dc 
  Revision: "0.01"
  Driver: "btusb"
  Driver Modules: "btusb"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v8087p07DCd0001dcE0dsc01dp01icE0isc01ip01in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: btusb is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe btusb"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #38 (Hub)
```

**sudo uname -a**

```
Linux mark-XPS-12-9Q33 3.11.0-intelwireless-wl #1 SMP Sat Sep 7 20:40:41 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**sudo lsb_release -a**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

**sudo dpkg -l | grep blue**

```
ii  blueman                                     1.23-0ubuntu2.1                         A Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluez                                       4.98-2ubuntu7                           Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-alsa                                  4.98-2ubuntu7                           Bluetooth ALSA support
ii  bluez-cups                                  4.98-2ubuntu7                           Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-gstreamer                             4.98-2ubuntu7                           Bluetooth GStreamer support
ii  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0                   3.2.2-0ubuntu5                          Introspection data for GnomeBluetooth
ii  gnome-bluetooth                             3.2.2-0ubuntu5                          GNOME Bluetooth tools
ii  libbluetooth3                               4.98-2ubuntu7                           Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  libgnome-bluetooth8                         3.2.2-0ubuntu5                          GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.3                       Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
```

**sudo hciconfig hci0 reset**

```
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

**hwinfo --bluetooth**

```
  [Created at usb.122]
  UDI: /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_8087_7dc_noserial_if0
  Unique ID: 7bWa.cdUiY6836R9
  Parent ID: pBe4.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 2-3:1.0
  Hardware Class: bluetooth
  Model: "Bluetooth Device"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x8087 
  Device: usb 0x07dc 
  Revision: "0.01"
  Driver: "btusb"
  Driver Modules: "btusb"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v8087p07DCd0001dcE0dsc01dp01icE0isc01ip01in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: btusb is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe btusb"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #4 (Hub)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'll even send you a beer! ;)

Comment: It would help others to catch your problem, if you attach a screenshot of Bluetooth windows..

Comment: I apologize, you are right. I have uploaded two screenshots, one of the bluetooth dropdown, and another of the bluetooth window that shows that it is enabled but does not allow for adding new devices.

http://postimg.org/image/j7bcdj6jf/

and 
http://postimg.org/image/70log4uyf/

Comment: Ok.. I would like to ask what actually you did? and also paste the result of `sudo uname -a` , `sudo lsb_release -a` and `sudo dpkg -l | grep blue` to your question..

Comment: I first updated my kernel to fix my wifi, since my computer is quite new i needed to install experimental drivers. Secondly, after rebooting into the custom kernel, everything was working. Then I started to remove unnesssary applications like Gwibber, Ubuntu One, Movie player, Rhythmbox, etc. None were core to the OS and that I know of, had anything to do with bluetooth. After rebooting, I see bluetooth "on" but it says it is disabled. It won't let me install or detect a new device. I'm guessing the adapter is not found?

Comment: That's fine!! But where is result of my commands.. Update it please..

Comment: Just updated it. I was working on formatting it.

Comment: Hmm!! Pretty strange.. you are using Updated 12.04.3 LTS with latest kernel and also installed all the bluetooth devices.. It seems that one package `bluetooth` is missing.. Install it with `sudo apt-get install bluetooth` then reconfigure packages with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` and then  update your grub to `sudo grub-update`. After all steps try to reboot your system. Once all steps completed reply me.. I'll be here only..

Comment: I am missing a lot of debs to do the dpkg-reconfigure, sorry if it's taking so long.

Comment: Ehhh... iirc Gwibber is core. Matter of fact, I wouldn't recommend removing any of those. I would re-install all those apps and then see if Bluetooth works. If it does, proceed to uninstall all the apps again from the terminal, one at a time, noting which packages and libraries they remove along with themselves.

Comment: @SauravKumar I receive this when executing the last command, and I'm not sure how to bypass it since I already have skype installed.

`mark@mark-XPS-12-9Q33:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
Package skype is not installed and no info is available.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: skype is not installed`

Comment: @markbratanov: ok before doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` try these commands: `sudo apt-get autoremove` , `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get -f install` then repeat all above steps..

Comment: Well It executed the last command, but after restarting the problem is the same. I think I might have to re-install the distro from 0 and try it again. Frustrating, I JUST got everything configured :-/

Comment: Ran another command, hci reset (included it in the original question at the bottom. Returns: `Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)`

Comment: Turns out somehow the bluetooth was disabled in UEFI. I DONT REMEMBER DOING THIS!? Anyways, problem solved. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @markbratanov: uff!! a sigh of relief!! good job.. better post it as an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from question body and as [mentioned by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343001/fixed-wireless-then-bluetooth-stopped-working#comment438870_343001):

> Make sure your bluetooth is ENABLED in BIOS/UEFI.